# Alternative definition of the mole?

Tags: mole

1 **amu** (atomic mass unit) is defined as the one twelfth of the mass of a carbon-12 atom. The **mole** is defined as the number of carbon-12 atom in 12 **g** of carbon-12. In other words,

$$\require{cancel} 1 \textbf{ mole} = \dfrac{12 \textbf{ g}}{m(^{12}C)} = \dfrac{\cancel{12} \textbf{ g}}{\cancel{12} \textbf{ amu}} = \dfrac{\textbf{ g}}{\textbf{ amu}} $$

I believe that the 12 **g** were chosen so that the **mole** could exacly express the ratio between the **g** and **amu**.

Consider now this alternative definition : the **amu** is defined as the exact mass of a proton and the **mole** is exact ratio between the **g** and the **amu**. Wouldn't it be simpler this way?

What are the advantages of one definition over the other? <s>Is there any reason we would want to keep the former?</s> Why scientists decided to define the mole like that and not pick a simpler definition like the one I proposed?

Comment: I wasn't very clear. See my edited question :)

Comment: Ah, ok. That's slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons to take Carbon-12 could be that it's hard to get your hands on one mole of pure hydrogen (and to weigh it). Carbon-12 is a (room temperature) solid which is relatively easy to produce, keep pure, store and weigh.

Comment: I believe that the mass of a proton has been derived experimentally with high precision. Why not define this as 1 **amu** = 1 **g/mol** and then express the mass of every atom accordingly? I don't understand where is the need to either weigh Carbon-12 of pure hydrogen.

Comment: @Corvinus - In addition to altering the molar masses of **everything**, the definition of the Avogadro constant is dependent on the definition of the unified atomic mass unit. Changing the definition of $\mathrm{u}$ would change the definition of $N_\mathrm{A}$, which would change the definition of the ideal gas constant $R$, since $R=N_\mathrm{A}k_\mathrm{B}$ (the latter term being the fundamental Boltzmann constant).

Comment: Actually, since $R$ is measurable (and $k_\mathrm{B}$ is not so easily measurable), changing $\mathrm{u}$ would change the Boltzmann constant, and all chemists and physicists would be upset.

Comment: I understand that it wouldn't make any sense to change the definition now. I see now that I wasn't very clear in my question : what I would like to understand is **why** scientists decided to define the **mole** like that and not pick a simpler definition like the one I proposed? (I'm editing my question to make that clearer)

Comment: I seriously doubt that any appreciable quantity of pure $\ce{^{12}C}$ exists. The mass of $\ce{^{13}C}$ is known to 13(?) significant figures and is about 1% of non-radioactive carbon. So you'd have to have $\ce{^{12}C}$ pure to about 12 significant figures to not perturb the mass. That just seems impossible for any reasonable mass of C.